# Whether Linux Kernel can be thought of as a single process

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

Whether Linux Kernel can be considered as a single process with many threads possible? Also what defines the switch between the memory management modules, scheduler, file system etc in the kernel.

Comment: The kernel by definition is not a process (since it runs on the bare metal). Processes need a kernel to be managed! Bare hardware don't know processes.

Comment: However the kernel *is* multi-threaded!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Linux kernel can't be considered as a process, because this is one of its responsibilities to manage processes.

You can consider kernel as a big interrupt handler. After the kernel grants processor to the thread, the only way to get control back are interrupts (or system calls, which are also interrupts). When interrupt occurs, kernel immediately gets control, and appropriately handles interrupt. At this point various parts of kernel could be called.

Kernel is multi-threaded as it can handle various interrupts on different processors simultaneously. On the other hand, there are kernel-threads, which are managed in the same way as user threads (there is no difference between kernel and user threads for scheduler).

Comment: `There is no difference between kernel and user threads for scheduler`. Then how these kernel threads are scheduled?

Comment: These kernel threads scheduled in the same way, as user threads, in the same queue, following the same rules. Scheduler even doesn't know whether thread is user thread or kernel one.

Comment: @user567879 Did I answer your question?

Comment: The kernel threads are scheduled **totally the same** way, as user-threads. To invoke scheduler, kernel issued `schedule()` function call. But process scheduling itself quite a big topic to describe it in comments.